# WebRTC video stream works on some devices but does not work on other devices

Tags: javascript, python, linux, webrtc, codec

I've been working on an app that uses webRTC and it works perfectly on all of MY devices from different networks. However, when other people try to use it from their devices, some can connect and some can't. I collected all the WebRTC chrome internal dumps and attached some of them below.

Local dump link:
https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=local_dump.txt

Working device(remote) dump link:
https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=working_device_dump.txt

Not working device(remote) dump link:
https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=not_working_dump.txt

Javascript is attached below:

I traversed a number of stackoverflow posts and my JS should be up-to-date. I am guessing the codecs are making the stream fail but I don't know what to fix.

```
// get DOM elements
var dataChannelLog = document.getElementById('data-channel'),
    iceConnectionLog = document.getElementById('ice-connection-state'),
    iceGatheringLog = document.getElementById('ice-gathering-state'),
    signalingLog = document.getElementById('signaling-state');

// peer connection
var pc = null;

// data channel
var dc = null, dcInterval = null;

function createPeerConnection() {
    var config = {
        sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan'
    };

    if (document.getElementById('use-stun').checked) {
        config.iceServers = [{urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']}];
    }

    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);


    // connect audio / video
    pc.addEventListener('track', function(evt) {
        if (evt.track.kind == 'video')
            document.getElementById('video').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
        else
            document.getElementById('audio').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
    });

    return pc;
}

function negotiate() {
    return pc.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function() {
        // wait for ICE gathering to complete
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        var offer = pc.localDescription;
        var codec;

        codec = document.getElementById('audio-codec').value;
//        if (codec !== 'default') {
//            offer.sdp = sdpFilterCodec('audio', codec, offer.sdp);
//        }
//
//        codec = document.getElementById('video-codec').value;
//        if (codec !== 'default') {
//            offer.sdp = sdpFilterCodec('video', codec, offer.sdp);
//        }

        document.getElementById('offer-sdp').textContent = offer.sdp;
        console.log(offer);

        return fetch('/offer', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sdp: offer.sdp,
                type: offer.type,
                video_transform: document.getElementById('video-transform').value
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer-sdp').textContent = answer.sdp;
        return pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        /*
        TODO: Presentation and logic mix a lot here (naturally). I don't think we need a framework (even though the
        JS world has ALL OF THEM), but maybe we can group all presentation related things in separate functions,
        for example change this to be catch(showConnectionError) and put the DOM logic inside
        function showConnectionError(e) {...}?
        */
            var el = document.querySelector('video');
            var newEl = document.createElement('img');
            newEl.src = '/working.png';
            newEl.style.height = '100%'
            el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
    });
}

function start() {
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';

    pc = createPeerConnection();

    var time_start = null;

    function current_stamp() {
        if (time_start === null) {
            time_start = new Date().getTime();
            return 0;
        } else {
            return new Date().getTime() - time_start;
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById('use-datachannel').checked) {
        var parameters = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('datachannel-parameters').value);

        dc = pc.createDataChannel('chat', parameters);
        dc.onclose = function() {
            clearInterval(dcInterval);
            dataChannelLog.textContent += '- close\n';
        };
        dc.onopen = function() {
            dataChannelLog.textContent += '- open\n';
            dcInterval = setInterval(function() {
                var message = 'ping ' + current_stamp();
                dataChannelLog.textContent += '> ' + message + '\n';
                dc.send(message);
            }, 1000);
        };
        dc.onmessage = function(evt) {
            dataChannelLog.textContent += '< ' + evt.data + '\n';

            if (evt.data.substring(0, 4) === 'pong') {
                var elapsed_ms = current_stamp() - parseInt(evt.data.substring(5), 10);
                dataChannelLog.textContent += ' RTT ' + elapsed_ms + ' ms\n';
            }
        };
    }

    var constraints = {
        audio: document.getElementById('use-audio').checked,
        video: false
    };

    if (document.getElementById('use-video').checked) {
        var resolution = document.getElementById('video-resolution').value;
        if (resolution) {
            resolution = resolution.split('x');
            constraints.video = {
                width: parseInt(resolution[0], 0),
                height: parseInt(resolution[1], 0)
            };
        } else {
            constraints.video = true;
        }
    }

    if (constraints.audio || constraints.video) {
        if (constraints.video) {
            document.getElementById('media').style.display = 'block';
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
            return negotiate();
        /*
        TODO: Can this also be promise-based? -> .catch(function(err) { ... })
        */
        }, function(err) {
            alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
        });
    } else {
        negotiate();
    }

    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

function stop() {
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';

    // close data channel
    if (dc) {
        dc.close();
    }

    // close transceivers
    if (pc.getTransceivers) {
        pc.getTransceivers().forEach(function(transceiver) {
            if (transceiver.stop) {
                transceiver.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    // close local audio / video
    pc.getSenders().forEach(function(sender) {
        sender.track.stop();
    });

    // close peer connection
    setTimeout(function() {
        pc.close();
    }, 500);
}

function sdpFilterCodec(kind, codec, realSdp) {
    var allowed = []
    var rtxRegex = new RegExp('a=fmtp:(\\d+) apt=(\\d+)\r$');
    var codecRegex = new RegExp('a=rtpmap:([0-9]+) ' + escapeRegExp(codec))
    var videoRegex = new RegExp('(m=' + kind + ' .*?)( ([0-9]+))*\\s*$')

    var lines = realSdp.split('\n');

    var isKind = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].startsWith('m=' + kind + ' ')) {
            isKind = true;
        } else if (lines[i].startsWith('m=')) {
            isKind = false;
        }

        if (isKind) {
            var match = lines[i].match(codecRegex);
            if (match) {
                allowed.push(parseInt(match[1]));
            }

            match = lines[i].match(rtxRegex);
            if (match && allowed.includes(parseInt(match[2]))) {
                allowed.push(parseInt(match[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    var skipRegex = 'a=(fmtp|rtcp-fb|rtpmap):([0-9]+)';
    var sdp = '';

    isKind = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].startsWith('m=' + kind + ' ')) {
            isKind = true;
        } else if (lines[i].startsWith('m=')) {
            isKind = false;
        }

        if (isKind) {
            var skipMatch = lines[i].match(skipRegex);
            if (skipMatch && !allowed.includes(parseInt(skipMatch[2]))) {
                continue;
            } else if (lines[i].match(videoRegex)) {
                sdp += lines[i].replace(videoRegex, '$1 ' + allowed.join(' ')) + '\n';
            } else {
                sdp += lines[i] + '\n';
            }
        } else {
            sdp += lines[i] + '\n';
        }
    }

    return sdp;
}

function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

Comment: Maybe the device just doesn't support how for e.g, the camera is accessed and that prevents it from working? I had an issue once where it didn't work because I counted on the camera being accessible the same way on all devices. Just a note that's all. Also please provide the code here or use pastebin or something so we don't have to sign in/ register to view your content on Dropbox.

Comment: Are you using a TURN server?  Most people can connect without one, but typically at least 10-15% of your users will require it.

Comment: All the test devices have an available webcam connected and in fact, the camera access prompt does show up in their browsers and the light on the camera is turned on. The tab also gets the red light as if the recording started. I attached the js.

Comment: I am only using STUN as you can see in the .js file I sampled across 7-8 different combos of devices, OSs and browsers and only 2 of them get the stream - the others do not.